# How to query a table based on data separated by delimiter in progress openedge 4gl?

Tags: field, delimiter, progress-4gl, openedge

I have a string

```
a = "test1;test2;test3;test4;test5;".
```

I need to query a table ( say table ) with each data separated by ";"

My query is :

```
For each table where table.field1 matches "*test1*" no-lock:

    disp table.field1 table.field2

end.
```

Answer (score 1):

Whilst your solution will work ok, there is a lot of overhead to it, particularly if the 'for each' is a slow query. You'd be better off creating a temp table of the values you want and adding that to the query. And as you're using 'matches' make sure field1 is in a decent index or performance will be horrible!

```
DEFINE VARIABLE v-cnt AS INTEGER     NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE segment AS longchar   NO-UNDO.

define temp-table tt-element no-undo
  field element as character
  index elidx is primary element.

assign segment = "abc;bcd;efg;".

do v-cnt = 1 to num-entries(segment,';'):
  create tt-element.
  tt-element.element = entry(v-cnt,segment,';').
end. 

for each tt-element,
  each table1 no-lock
  where table1.field1 matches '*' + tt-element.element + '*':
  message table1.field1
    view-as alert-box info buttons ok.
end.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DEFINE VARIABLE v-cnt AS INTEGER     NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE segment AS longchar   NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE eachelement AS CHARACTER   NO-UNDO.

assign segment = "abc;bcd;efg;".

DO v-cnt = 1 TO num-entries(segment, ";") - 1  :

ASSIGN eachelement = string(entry(v-cnt, segment, ";")).

FOR each table1 where table1.field1 matches "*" + eachelement + "*"  no-lock:

       MESSAGE table1.field1 
           VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX INFO BUTTONS OK.
END.
END.
```